# Insert frames into the middle of the timeline

Tags: 3ds-max

I have a 3ds Max file with a set of animations done already (about 2500 frames). I would like to add a pause at frame 1000 for 1 second (30 extra frames). Is there a way to insert frames into the middle of the timeline? If I use the "Time Configuration" dialog to add more frames to the animation they go at the end, and I don't want to have to then go redo most of the animations to be 30 frames later.

Or alternately, is there a way to shift all keys after 1000 by a set number of frames (+30, in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I will interrupt a box's movement along the x axis at frame 15 (of the 30 frame animation). As with all things in Max, there are many ways to do something.

[image]

1. Using the set key command together with the key button, create a key at the point on the timeline where you'd like to add your 30 frames (if one doesn't already exist). If not, create another key in the adjacent spot to its right. Turn off Set Key. [image]

[image]

2. Open your Track View Curve editor in the main toolbar. [image]

[image]

3. Select the animation parameters you wish to freeze in time for 30 frames. In my case, it's only movement along 1 axis, but be sure to select all of your pertinent tracks.

[image]

4. Using the Move Keys tool, select all keyframes from frame 16 until the last one by drawing a marquee over the entire area to highlight. Drag all highlighted keys to the right by 30 frames (or however long you want to add a pause).

[image]

5. Using the a) Move Keys tool, click on the b) first key, copy its c) value, then click on the second key and paste that value.

[image]